# onClick doesn't work properly

Tags: android, database, post

Here is my Class. In OnClick method i'm trying to post data to the remote db, but nothing happend. I don't know totally why. No errors, no action. Just nothing. Any answers are welcome. Please help.

```
public class Wyslij extends Activity {

protected static final int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 5000;

ImageButton ib_wyslij;
int suma_zam;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.wyslij);


    ib_wyslij = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ib_wyslij);

    final Zamowienie zam = new Zamowienie();



    String suma_zamowienia = podaj_sume(TowarZamowienie.towary_zamowione);
    if(suma_zamowienia != null && !suma_zamowienia.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

    suma_zam = Integer.parseInt(suma_zamowienia);
        zam.suma=suma_zam;}

    zam.suma=suma_zam;


    TowarZamowienie tz = new TowarZamowienie();

    ib_wyslij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("Zam_suma", zam.getSuma());

                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                        TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                //
                //String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/sample1/webservice2.php?" + 
                //             "json={\"UserName\":1,\"FullName\":2}";
                String url = "http://www.msinzynierka.cba.pl/executeConn.php";

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(json.toString().getBytes(
                        "UTF8")));
                request.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need

            } catch (Throwable t) {

            }
            //sendAccelerationData(zam);

        }
});

}

private String podaj_sume(ArrayList<Towar> l) {
    int suma = 0;
    String s = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        suma += l.get(i).Tow_ilosc * l.get(i).Tow_cena;
    }

    return s = String.valueOf(suma);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't catch a general Exception and don't print it - that way, you won't get any hint in case of an exception. Simply change the throwable to exception and call yourException.printStacktrace();

I bet the Exception you get is a [`NetworkingOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). Networking operations tend to take some time, and that's why it's forbidden to perform such actions on the main (ui) thread in Android. This would make the UI unresponsive, which leads to a very bad user experience.

Have a look at `AsyncTask` for gracefully moving the operation to a background thread.

Comment: Can I get an example of implementation with AsyncTask?